# How to embed external js code into React component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I am working in a project, where I have to use a widget_api code provided by **[RIPE Stat](https://stat.ripe.net/docs/widget_api)**, to integrate the graphical widget into a React component.
For example in HTML5, I would have done it like this, and it works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Widget</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <script src="https://stat.ripe.net/widgets/widget_api.js"></script>
    <div class="statwdgtauto">
        <script>
            ripestat.init("rir-geo",{"resource":"80.12.67.0/24"},null,{"size":"500","disable":["controls"]})
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

While doing research I found this **[react-safe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-safe)** library which allows to do the same thing in React

Here is the code of my index file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
   
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>MyWHOIS</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body class="bd-home">
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="./js/polyfill.js" defer ></script>
    <script src="https://stat.ripe.net/widgets/widget_api.js" async></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

And the component that I created for...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Safe from "react-safe";

export default class EmbedComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super();
        /*
        const widget_api = document.createElement("script");
        widget_api.src = "https://stat.ripe.net/widgets/widget_api.js";
        widget_api.async = true;
    
        document.body.appendChild(widget_api);
       */
    }

    render() {
        const params1 = {"family":4,"warnings":1,"delegated":1,"resource":"FR"};
        const params2 ={"resource":"127.0.0.1/24"};
        const control = {"size":"500","disable":["controls"]};
        return (
            <div>
                <h4>Include Embed</h4>
                <div className="statwdgtauto">
                    <Safe.script>
                        {`ripestat.init("rpki-by-country",${params1},null,${control})`}
                    </Safe.script>
                    <Safe.script>
                        {`ripestat.init("rir-geo",${params2},null,${control})`}
                    </Safe.script>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I have errors, when I include the file with the  tag with async or defer, I have a cors error

> A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, , is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message. See  for more details.

And without defer or async I have this problem of writing on the document

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened. widget_api.js:90

Answer (score 0):

Define a new state isLoading

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
  const widget_api = document.createElement("script");
  widget_api.src = "https://stat.ripe.net/widgets/widget_api.js";
  widget_api.async = true;
  // Wait for the onload here
  widget_api.script.onload = () => setState({isLoading: false})
  document.body.appendChild(widget_api);
}
```

and on you render function do something during the isLoading phase (you can display a loader instead of your current implementation)

Comment: It doesn't change anything, I always have the same warning. > widget_api.js:90 Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are locked into an implementation detail of `ripeStat` which prevents use of it in some of the modrn frameworks, react for instance.

If you look at the `ripeStat` code, here for instance, https://stat.ripe.net/widgets/widget_api.js you see that it has calls to `document.write`.

`document.write` would not kick in, in a deferred situation and is expected.Check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write#notes and you will find the same error that you are seeing.

[image]

Once the document has been read, parsed and closed, `document.write` calls will not be entertained.

I think this is a limitation of the `ripeStat` library. What they should use instead is

```js
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://stat.ripe.net/widgets/widget_api.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

which will ensure that it works across the board correctly.

Another option, which is probably a better one is for an npm package from `ripeStat` which will help the moderm frameworks.

The only way it will work correctly right now within your react application is that the script has to be present before the browser starts parsing your HTML and interpreting it.